# How does $\{\gamma^\mu , \gamma^\nu\}= 2g^{\mu\nu}I$ imply that $\gamma^\mu$ is traceless?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace, clifford-algebra

How does $\{\gamma^\mu , \gamma^\nu\}= 2g^{\mu\nu}I$ imply that $\gamma^\mu$ is traceless?

*where I represents the identity matrix*

I know that  $$\{\gamma^\mu , \gamma^\nu\}=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu \tag{1}$$ and that

$$g^{\mu\nu}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$

I know the real values of the gamma matrices but I suppose I am meant to ignore the fact that I know those values and simply use $g^{\mu\nu}$ as the reason behind their tracelessness.

I have attempted using $(1)$ by only "paying attention" (for the lack of better words) to the diagonal terms, as follows:

$$\gamma^\mu= \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and multiplying this by a similar matrix with diagonal terms e,f,g,h.

This led me nowhere.

Comment: Wikipedia has a proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities

Answer (score 6):

Using the relation, we know that 
$
\frac{\gamma^b \gamma^b}{2g^{bb}} = 1
$.
Thus, assuming $a\ne b$ we write
\begin{align}
Tr(\gamma^a) &= \frac{1}{2g^{bb}}Tr(\gamma^a \gamma^b \gamma^b)
\end{align}
This can be manipulated in two ways:

1. Using a cyclic permutation property of the trace, we obtain
   $$
   Tr(\gamma^a) =\frac{1}{2g^{bb}}Tr(\gamma^b \gamma^a \gamma^b)
   $$
2. Using the (anti-)commutation relation 
   $\gamma^a \gamma^b = − \gamma^b \gamma^a$
   for $a\ne b$. 
   $$
   Tr(\gamma^a) = -\frac{1}{2g^{bb}}Tr(\gamma^b \gamma^a \gamma^b)
   $$

Both conditions must be satisfied. This is only possible if the trace is zero.